# Can I put static_assert in class method if I never call this method?

Tags: c++, static

This version doesn't compile at all:

```
struct A {
    void foo() {
        static_assert(0,"Fail");
    }
};
```

This version compiles without errors (at least in my version of compiler):

```
template <int x>
struct B {
    void foo() {
        static_assert(x,"Fail");
    }
};
B<0> b;
```

The second version fails to compile only when I call `b.foo();`, so I want to know is it permitted by the standard to use the second version if I never call method `foo`? Will all compilers behave in the same way? Isn't it undefined behavior?

I want to include `static_assert` in the code to forbid usage of some methods of a template class when some template parameters meet some criteria. Is it correct usage of `static_assert`?

I want to use this approach (I want to forbid usage of `.z()` when vector has only two dimensions) in this situation:

```
template <typename T, int D>
struct MyVecctor {
    MyVecctor() : data({})
    {}
    template <typename... Args>
    MyVecctor(Args... args) : data({args...})
    {
        static_assert(D > 0);
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == D);
    }
    T& operator[] (std::size_t index) {
        return data[index];
    }
    T& x() {
        static_assert(D>=1);
        return data[0];
    }
    T& y() {
        static_assert(D>=2);
        return data[1];
    }
    T& z() {
        static_assert(D>=3);
        return data[2];
    }
    std::array<T, D> data;
};
```

Comment: Template code only needs to be syntactically correct until instantiated, so yes.

Comment: This usage maybe fine, but it will not prevent you from calling it but instantiating it. There is difference btw that two cases. You better ask what you want to achieve rather than if this code is fine.

Comment: Your approach seems wrong, probably better is to have such method undefined for some cases (using `std::enable_if` for example) and then compiler will reject to call such method. Again you better ask what you want to achieve, possibly with pseudocode, rather that asking if this is code compiles/valid.

Comment: @Slava How it is possible to call `foo` without instantiation? (in response to "it will not prevent you from calling it but instantiating it.")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do template classes allow member functions which cannot compile?](//stackoverflow.com/q/31328754)

Comment: @Slava, use a proper tool: `std::enable_if` to exclude a method from candidates during overload resolution, and `static_assert` to prevent a method from calling. These a different concepts in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bodies of a template class's methods are not instantiated unless called.

However, if we consider the instantiation of bodies of a template class's methods to be template instantiations (this is unclear in the standard), then there must be a valid set of template arguments that makes the body possible to instantiate; otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

In your specific case, `static_assert(x, "Fail")` clearly has a valid instantiation (any `x!=0`).  So you are safe.

However

```
void foo() {
  static_assert(x&&!x, "Fail");
}
```

isn't going to be safe; by my reading, that is an ill-formed program with no diagnostic required.  On the other hand, my reading might be wrong; the standard is pretty oblique here.

The philosophical reason why the above is wrong is that it permits compilers to detect for impossible assumptions in static asserts; it lets the compiler check *more* things in the bodies of templates than the standard demands, which is I believe why the standard makes uninstantable templates ill-formed, and no diagnostic requried is because they don't want to have to force every compiler to do every kind of diagnostic for every kind of uninstantiable template (which requires solving Halt).

So philosphically, your `static_assert`s in non-template methods should be possible to pass for some template arguments passed to the containing template class.

Things get murkier when you have a template method to a template class which is impossible to instantiate for certain template arguments to the template class.  But that is going down a rabbit hole.

I am sufficiently uncertain about that last case that I avoid doing it, and instead use CRTP to conditionally have the method exist or not.

Comment: You saying "So you are safe." when using `static_assert(x, "Fail")` and instantiate `B<0>`, but later you say that "Things get murkier when you have a template method to a template class which is impossible to instantiate for certain template arguments to the template class." it seems opposite to me. I don't catch the difference between both cases, but you saying the first is ok, but the second may be wrong.

Comment: @BhavinChirag Wll, `void foo()` is a non-template method of a template class.  `template<class T> void bar()` is a template method of a template class.  Depending on how you read the standard (it is obtuse here), `static_assert( x, "Fail" )` in the second case might make your program ill formed, as `B<0>::bar` is a template that cannot be instantiated.  Meanwhile, `foo` as a non-template method if it is a template instantiation is a template instantiation of `B<x>::foo`, and there are valid `x` for which the body can be instantiated.

Comment: I think "philosophical reason" paragraph is heading in the wrong direction and the actual purpose of allowing non-instantiable templates to make program ill-formed without diagnostic is to permit compilers check *less* things in the bodies of templates and to allow them silently fail if they encounter something too fancy. If it wasn't for the twisted C++'s rules, having non-instantiable templates silently making program ill-formed even without trying to instantiate template would be similar to making `terminate` function silently terminate the program even without invoking it.

Comment: @VTT Sure, it permits that too.  It can assume the code can be instantiated, optimize based on that, and then generate gobblygook executable code.  But the idea of permitting additional checks in templates is important, many compilers do it.

Comment: As for `static_assert(x&&!x, "Fail");` case someone made a good point in some  similar question (which I struggle to find now...), something along the line "it does not actually make template specializations non-instantiable or otherwise invalid (unlike array with negative size for example), `static_assert` makes program ill-formed". I guess this is really confusing.

Answer (score 8):

The behavior here is well-defined. The significant difference here is that in second case result of `static_assert` depends on template parameter so it won't be resolved until this method is instantiated. If it didn't depend on template parameter then it would fail just like in first case without instantiating anything:

```
template <int x>
struct B {
    void foo() {
        static_assert(0,"Fail");
    }
};
```

And yes, forbidding usage of some methods of a template class when some template parameters met some criteria is a correct usage of `static_assert`. And I would even say this is a preferred method of prohibiting method because it may yield a more readable error message (even with a potential fix suggestion) compared to usual template instantiation failure gibberish.

Comment: So, am I understand your correctly, that instantiation happens when `foo` called, but not when `B<0> b;` is used?

Comment: No, you did not.

Comment: @BhavinChirag instantiation (of `foo`) happens only when `foo` is actually called, it does not happen automatically when template class itself is instantiated

Comment: An important example needed here is `static_assert(x&&!x, "Fail");` which makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required; most compilers will behave like `static_assert(x, "Fail");` in that they won't generate an early error, but they are free to do *anything*.  If they follow your last paragraph advice without being aware of that trap they can easliy make broken programs.

Answer (score 1):

With C++2a, you might use `requires`:

```
void foo() requires (x != 0)
{
    /*..*/
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77c161de92a09604)

Answer (score 0):

[Static Assertion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) `static_assert(bool_constexpr, message)` performs **compile-time** assertion checking.

> If bool_constexpr returns true, this declaration has no effect.
>   Otherwise a compile-time error is issued, and the text of message, if
>   any, is included in the diagnostic message.

Your code is `static_assert(0,"Fail")` Because of that `0` it will assert. But, if the bool expresion depends on a template parameter (or a function parameter), it has no value at compile time (unless you use a default value), and can not assert.

`static_assert(x,"Fail")` may assert if the compiler knows that `x= false`. Using `B<0> b` is not enough for the compiler. The assertion is done inside `foo()`. If this member is used, which means that this member function is instantiated, then the compiler does assert.

*Can I put static_assert in class method if I never call this method?*

> A static assert declaration may appear at namespace and block scope
>   (as a block declaration) and inside a class body (as a member
>   declaration)

So, yes, you can.

Comment: *"But, if the bool expresion depends on a template parameter (or a function parameter), it has no value at compile time"* Shouldn't it have the value of the template parameter (known at compile time)?

Comment: @Bob__ template parameter: `int x`. Which value is assigned to `x` at compile-time?

Comment: `B<0> b;` -> `0`

Comment: @Bob__ In this case `B<0> b` is not enough for the compiler because it `b` is not used it's optimized out. But add `b.foo()` and now it asserts. This is the case I meant with "default value". Perhaps I improve my answer.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with optimization.

Comment: Please note this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wri1TtTcUldBmfG6 Here `b` is not optimized out, but it still compile, becuase `foo` is not instantiated.

Comment: @Bob__ In your code `b` **is**  instantiated, `foo` is optimized out.

Comment: @BaummitAugen True. The right word is *member instantiation*. "Optimized out" has a similar effect, on different context. I've edited my answer.